Access is denied with win32security though running with administrative privileges
This is a sample project I am working on, it is in it beginning stages but I keep getting Access is denied even though I am running the program with administrative privileges.
I am on windows 11. Python3.11
Help will be very much appreciated
import win32security
import win32api
import win32con
import psutil
import pywintypes
import ctypes

def privileges():
    
    def elevate_privileges():

        privelege_value = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, win32security.SE_DEBUG_NAME)
        token_handle = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES)

        win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(
            token_handle, False, [(privelege_value, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
        )

    if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        print("Script has administrative priviledges...")

        try:

            elevate_privileges()
            print("Priviledges elevated...")

        except pywintypes.error as e:

            print(e.strerror)
    else:
        print("Script does not have administrative priviledges...")
        
privileges()

Manifest file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity
        version="1.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        name="module"
        type="win32"
    />
    <description>Your Script Description</description>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel
                    level="requireAdministrator"
                    uiAccess="false"
                />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>


Command I use to build and run the program
pyinstaller --onefile --name prog --uac-admin -m module.exe.manifest program.py
./dist/prog.exe
The program triggers the UAC prompt, the programs runs with administrative privileges but I am still getting the error "Access is denied."
